SingleStore Procedure RowLock Issue
I have the SINGLESTORE stored procedure shown here which is going into rowlocks while inserting 8 million rows. Inserting 60k-80k, it runs fine.
The error that I am receiving is below. I am not sure, how can I change this query and run it in blocks to avoid locks. Could someone suggest me a better solution. I want this to run row by row but without locks.
call name('ABC');


Found row lock conflict( owned by connection 62269 in node x. retrying  statement in 35 seconds, insert into GG .....)

create or replace procedure name (prcs) returns void as
declare 

R query(id text, cd txt, date timetamp(6), date_2 timestamp(6));
r_arr array(record(id text, cd txt, date timetamp(6), date_2 timestamp(6)));
tbnm=varchar(25);
exception_message text='';
begin
if prcs ='A' then
tbnm='X';
R=select X.id , X.cd , X.date, Z.date_2 from X inner join z on X.id=z.id;
else 
tbnm='Y';
R=select Y.id , Y.cd , Y.date, Z.date_2 from Y inner join z on Y.id=z.id;
endif;

r_arr=collect(r);

for record in r_arr loop
if record.cd='I' and record.date_2>=record.date1
then
execute immediate concat('insert into log_tbl values (current_timestamp, prcs, record.id, record.cd, 'Reject')');
end if;
if
(record.cd='I' and record.date_2<record.date)
then 
begin
execute immediate concate('insert into GG select *  /*all columns*/
from 'tbnm' x where x.id=record.id');
exception
when others then 
begin 
exception_message=exception_message();
exception_message=replace(replace(exception_message,'`',''),'\'','');
excecute immedate concat('insert into log_tbl values(current_timestamp, prcs, record.id, record.cd, 'Fail')');
end;
end if;
end loop;
end;

I have tried passing table name as input parameter but it did not work as well. I feel the insert statement is a problem.

You need to see what is this 62269 running.
select * from information_schema.mv_processlist;
check what is this 62269 doing.
And can increase the timeout.
